# Joining multiple tables to get a post comment

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.post (
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar NOT NULL,
    "content" text NOT NULL,
    location_details varchar NOT NULL,
    datetime timestamptz NOT NULL,
    "blocked" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    anonymous bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT post_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT post1_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.post_comments (
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    post_id varchar NOT NULL,
    "content" text NOT NULL,
    date_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT post_comments_id_post_id_key UNIQUE (id, post_id),
    CONSTRAINT post_comments_post_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id),
    CONSTRAINT post_comments_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.post_photos (
    post_id varchar NOT NULL,
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    date_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    title varchar NULL,
    description text NULL,
    "path" varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT post_photos_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT post_photos_post_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.tag_post (
    tag_id varchar NOT NULL,
    post_id varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tag_post_tag_id_post_id_key UNIQUE (tag_id, post_id),
    CONSTRAINT tag_post_post_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id),
    CONSTRAINT tag_post_tag_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tags(id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.tags (
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    description text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tags_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I have to join these table in PostgreSQL, i am doing the following query:

```
select distinct p.id, pc.id, p."content",  p.anonymous, p.datetime, p.location_details, p.user_id, ph.id, ph."path", ph.title, ph.date_time, tp.tag_id from post p 
    left JOIN post_comments pc on p.id=pc.post_id
    left JOIN post_photos ph on p.id=ph.post_id 
    left JOIN tag_post tp on p.id=tp.post_id
    where p.id='863550630468626253'
    group by p.id, pc.id
```

I am getting this error

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "ph.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 242
```

Basically this query is supposed to get a post and it's latest comments, tags, photos of a post. Here is the table's data:

`post`

```
id                |user_id            |content         |location_details|datetime           |blocked|anonymous|
------------------|-------------------|----------------|----------------|-------------------|-------|---------|
863550630468626253|1665058285911882257|Hi hello jwje 23|Mumbai     |2019-04-07 00:08:11|false  |false    |
```

`tag_post`

```
tag_id  post_id
java    863550630468626253
tech    863550630468626253
```

`post_comments`

```
id                  |post_id           |content                                  |date_time          |user_id            |
--------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
1727639960713835685 |863550630468626253|hello comment1!<b>ss</b>                 |2019-04-09 19:08:55|1665058285911882257|
-7642691544064884314|863550630468626253|hello comment12mm3!<b>ss</b>             |2019-04-09 20:18:17|1665058285911882257|
579985859487432237  |863550630468626253|hello hjjh  jhjhjh comment12mm3!<b>ss</b>|2019-04-09 20:22:45|1665058285911882257|
-2764275200080807769|863550630468626253|hello hjjh  jhjhjh comment12mm3!<b>ss</b>|2019-04-09 20:40:28|1665058285911882257|
```

`post_photos`

```
post_id|id|date_time|title|description|path|
-------|--|---------|-----|-----------|----|
```

Comment: You will need another query to retrieve your photos, as a post can have several photos, you can't select them this way.

Answer (score 0):

you have not used any aggregate function so dont need group by i think you need row_number()

```
with cte as
(select  p.id, pc.id, p."content",
  p.anonymous, p.datetime, 
p.location_details, p.user_id, ph.id, ph."path",
 ph.title, ph.date_time, tp.tag_id 
 ,row_number()over(partition by  p.id order by datetime desc) rn
   from post p 
    left JOIN post_comments pc on p.id=pc.post_id
    left JOIN post_photos ph on p.id=ph.post_id 
    left JOIN tag_post tp on p.id=tp.post_id
    where p.id='863550630468626253'
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: post id `863550630468626253` has four comments in `post_comments` , two tag in `tag_post` and zero photos in `post_photos`. Your query is just showing one row

Comment: I updated the question with data. your query output is `id                |id                 |content         |anonymous|datetime           |location_details|user_id            |id|path|title|date_time|tag_id|rn|
------------------|-------------------|----------------|---------|-------------------|----------------|-------------------|--|----|-----|---------|------|--|
863550630468626253|1727639960713835685|Hi hello jwje 23|false    |2019-04-07 00:08:11|Mumbai     |1665058285911882257|  |    |     |         |java  | 1|`

Comment: @manish what is the expected output from the among updated sample data

Comment: but i am not getting all comments and its tag for a given post